# Trying to redirect from one directory to antoher, under the same domain

Tags: redirect

i have a website with wordpress installed on it on 2 directories.
i am trying to redirect for example a 
http://www.website.com/archive/7 --->http://www.website.com/login

i tried the cpanel in bluehost adn it doesnt seem to work or it sets up an infinite loop.
i also just began with creating websites adn i dont have the knowledge of editing the .htacess file

Answer (score 0):

There many different redirects you can perform with web servers. The most efficient (after DNS redirects) are at the web server level (i.e. .htaccess you mentioned with modRewrite), but you can also do a http redirect if this is too difficult or too time consuming and you want a quick fix.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>optional title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.website.com/login"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<h1>Optional page text here.</h1>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

You can also perform various redirects with PHP, ASP, and other server side and client side code.

Specifically redirection for wordpress (5th post): [Wordpress Redirect](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/forum-tab?replies=11)